# How prematurely can one withdraw from NSC?

Tags: india, options-clearing

I have purchased NSC in April 2011.

I would like to withdraw the same. Is it possible? If yes what procedure do I have to follow?

Also tell whether the same can be withdrawn from any one post office in India or do I have to visit the issuing post office for the withdrawal of the same?

Also guide if a person has claimed tax benefit for the same then what is the impact of the same on the filed I-tax Return?

Answer (score 1):

[It seems the minimum time after which you can withdraw the investment prematurely is 3 years.](http://www.indiapost.gov.in/netscape/6yearsNSC.html). But I did read somewhere that if you encash it before 1 year you only get the face value. If after more than 1 year and less than 3 years you would only get simple interest, no compounded interest, on your investment amount. Better drop in into your nearest post office and have a chat with the guys. That would be the sure shot way.